# Training an RNN with examples of different lengths in Keras

Tags: python, keras, rnn, training

I am trying to get started learning about RNNs and I'm using Keras. I understand the basic premise of vanilla RNN and LSTM layers, but I'm having trouble understanding a certain technical point for training.

In the [keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/), it says the input to an RNN layer must have shape `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`. This suggests that all the training examples have a fixed sequence length, namely `timesteps`.

But this is not especially typical, is it? I might want to have the RNN operate on sentences of varying lengths. When I train it on some corpus, I will feed it batches of sentences, all of different lengths.

I suppose the obvious thing to do would be to find the max length of any sequence in the training set and zero pad it. But then does that mean I can't make predictions at test time with input length greater than that?

This is a question about Keras's particular implementation, I suppose, but I'm also asking for what people typically do when faced with this kind of a problem in general.

Comment: @kbrose is correct. However, I have one concern. In the example, you have a very special generator of infinitely yields. More importantly, it is designed to yield batches of size 1000. In practice, this is too hard to satisfy, if not impossible. You need to re-organize your entries so those with the same length are arranged together, and you need to carefully set batch split positions. Moreover, you have no chance to make shuffle across the batches. So my opinion is: never use varying length input in Keras unless you exactly know what you are doing. Use padding and set `Masking` layer to ignor

Answer (score 104):

> This suggests that all the training examples have a fixed sequence length, namely `timesteps`.

That is not quite correct, since that dimension can be `None`, i.e. variable length. Within a single *batch*, you must have the same number of timesteps (this is typically where you see 0-padding and masking). But between batches there is no such restriction. During inference, you can have any length.

Example code that creates random time-length batches of training data.

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, TimeDistributed
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 5)))
model.add(LSTM(8, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')))

print(model.summary(90))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam')

def train_generator():
    while True:
        sequence_length = np.random.randint(10, 100)
        x_train = np.random.random((1000, sequence_length, 5))
        # y_train will depend on past 5 timesteps of x
        y_train = x_train[:, :, 0]
        for i in range(1, 5):
            y_train[:, i:] += x_train[:, :-i, i]
        y_train = to_categorical(y_train > 2.5)
        yield x_train, y_train

model.fit_generator(train_generator(), steps_per_epoch=30, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

And this is what it prints. Note the output shapes are `(None, None, x)` indicating variable batch size and variable timestep size.

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                            Output Shape                        Param #
==========================================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                           (None, None, 32)                    4864
__________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                           (None, None, 8)                     1312
__________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDistributed)    (None, None, 2)                     18
==========================================================================================
Total params: 6,194
Trainable params: 6,194
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/10
30/30 [==============================] - 6s 201ms/step - loss: 0.6913
Epoch 2/10
30/30 [==============================] - 4s 137ms/step - loss: 0.6738
...
Epoch 9/10
30/30 [==============================] - 4s 136ms/step - loss: 0.1643
Epoch 10/10
30/30 [==============================] - 4s 142ms/step - loss: 0.1441
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However, if we 0 pad the sequences, it will affect the hidden states and memory cell because we continue passing x_t as 0s, when if fact, there should be nothing passed. In the normal `fit()`, we can pass the `sequence_lenth` parameter to specify the length of the sequence to exclude it. It seems that the generator approach doesn't allow ignoring 0 sequences?

Comment: @GRS Your generator can return a 3-tuple of `(inputs, targets, sample_weights)`, and you can set `sample_weights` of your 0-pads to 0. However, I'm not sure this would work perfectly for Bidirectional RNNs.

Comment: This has been helpful, but I wish it would also include an example of using `model.predict_generator` with a test set. When I try to predict with a generator I get an error regarding concatenation (the test set also has variable length sequences). My solution has been to use the standard `model.predict` in a hacky way. Perhaps this would just be better fit for a new question?

Comment: @mickey that sounds like a different question. This question is about training, not prediction.

Comment: If the question in the comments was indeed asked as a new question, can you link to it?

Answer (score 12):

@kbrose seems to have a better solution

> I suppose the obvious thing to do would be to find the max length of any sequence in the training set and zero pad it.

This is usually a good solution. Maybe try max length of sequence + 100. Use whatever works best for your application.

> But then does that mean I can't make predictions at test time with input length greater than that?

Not necessarily. The reason a fixed length is used in keras, is because it greatly improves performance by creating tensors of fixed shapes. But that's only for training. After training, you'll have learned the right weights for your task.

Let's assume, after training for hours, you realise your model's max length wasn't big/small enough and you now need to change the time steps, just extract the learned weights from the old model, build a new model with the new time steps and inject the learned weights into it.

You can probably do this using something like:

`new_model.set_weights(old_model.get_weights())`

I haven't tried it out myself. Please try it and post your results here for everyone's benefit. Here are some links:
[one](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5348) [two](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/91)

Comment: You can indeed have variable length inputs, no need to introduce hacks like `max length + 100`. See my answer for example code.

Comment: Transferring the weights to a model with more timesteps does indeed work perfectly fine! I bumped up the timesteps for `Bidirectional(LSTM)()` and `RepeatVector()` layers, and the predictions are perfectly viable.

Comment: @kbrose This is not a hack, it is how you normally do it. Using a batch_size of one is too slow and keras enable masking layers so that the masking doesn't affect loss.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to create a variable-length LSTM autoencoder the way you described, however the problem is when you use the LSTM for many times, then many models get created since you have to create an entire new one and load the old weights for each variable-length instance, then the memory slowly accumulates, then you would have to use K.clear_session() however this would clear up everything, and if there are other stuff you want not to be cleared then it would be very bad to fix.