# How can RNN handle variable sized inputs?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, rnn

I came across this answer which is specific to Keras. But my question is at concept level. I am getting confused, How can RNN handle variable size inputs?
[here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26366/training-an-rnn-with-examples-of-different-lengths-in-keras)

Let us suppose we want to do a  sentiment classification

**Training batches of different length** : Which I think means all training examples in a batch must be of same length but different batches can have variable length training examples.

Now, suppose length of training examples in

- batch-1 = 10,
- batch-2 = 15.

Now while training batch-1 , the RNN unrolls and there would be 10 columns in the below figure to handle input of sequence 10. The shared weights **W, U,V** dimensions must be in sync with sequence length. I mean the shared weights would be **w1,w2,..w10** .  I understand till this part.

Now, in While processing **batch-2** which is of sequence length 15, The unrolled RNN must take sequence of length 15. That means there are 15 columns in the below figure .

The number of weights changed from 10(w1,w2,...w10) to 15(w1,w2,..w15). 
Things don't add up here for me.

What happens to shared weights? How are they learnt?

[image]